# Where the Field "value" is declared?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I'm new on apache storm and kafka and try to learn these notions via courses provided by OpenClassroom.The principle is simple, messages are sent via a python program to a kafka server, and are retrieved via a kafka spout defined in the main class of a Storm topology. The problem is that I don't understand how the bolt retrieves the messages. From what I understand this is done in the `ParsingBolt` class with the following line of code: `JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)jsonParser.parse(input.getStringByField("value"));`. The only thing is that I don't understand how we know that the messages are contained in the `value` field. Below you can find the `main` class and the `parsing bolt` class. (The whole project is available [here](https://github.com/oc-courses/gerez-des-flux-de-donnees-temps-reel/tree/master/velos/src/main/java/velos))

The `main` class:

```java
package velos;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.storm.Config;
import org.apache.storm.LocalCluster;
import org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter;
import org.apache.storm.generated.AlreadyAliveException;
import org.apache.storm.generated.AuthorizationException;
import org.apache.storm.generated.InvalidTopologyException;
import org.apache.storm.generated.StormTopology;
import org.apache.storm.kafka.spout.KafkaSpout;
import org.apache.storm.kafka.spout.KafkaSpoutConfig;
import org.apache.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;
import org.apache.storm.topology.base.BaseWindowedBolt;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Fields;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws AlreadyAliveException, InvalidTopologyException, AuthorizationException {
        TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

        KafkaSpoutConfig.Builder<String, String> spoutConfigBuilder = KafkaSpoutConfig.builder("localhost:9092",
                "velib-stations");
        spoutConfigBuilder.setProp(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "city-stats");
        KafkaSpoutConfig<String, String> spoutConfig = spoutConfigBuilder.build();
        builder.setSpout("stations", new KafkaSpout<String, String>(spoutConfig));

        builder.setBolt("station-parsing", new StationParsingBolt()).shuffleGrouping("stations");

        builder.setBolt("city-stats",
                new CityStatsBolt().withTumblingWindow(BaseWindowedBolt.Duration.of(1000 * 60 * 5)))
                .fieldsGrouping("station-parsing", new Fields("city"));

        builder.setBolt("save-results", new SaveResultsBolt()).fieldsGrouping("city-stats", new Fields("city"));

        StormTopology topology = builder.createTopology();

        Config config = new Config();
        config.setMessageTimeoutSecs(60 * 30);
        String topologyName = "Velos";
        if (args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("remote")) {
            StormSubmitter.submitTopology(topologyName, config, topology);
        } else {
            LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
            cluster.submitTopology(topologyName, config, topology);
        }
    }
}
```

The `ParsingBolt`:

```java
 package velos;

import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.storm.task.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.storm.task.TopologyContext;
import org.apache.storm.topology.OutputFieldsDeclarer;
import org.apache.storm.topology.base.BaseRichBolt;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Fields;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Tuple;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Values;
import org.apache.storm.shade.org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.apache.storm.shade.org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.apache.storm.shade.org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class StationParsingBolt extends BaseRichBolt {
    private OutputCollector outputCollector;
    
    @Override
    public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
        outputCollector = collector;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Tuple input) {
        try {
            process(input);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            outputCollector.fail(input);
        }
    }
    
    public void process(Tuple input) throws ParseException {
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)jsonParser.parse(input.getStringByField("value"));
        String contract = (String)obj.get("contract_name");
        Long availableStands = (Long)obj.get("available_bike_stands");
        Long stationNumber = (Long)obj.get("number");
        
        outputCollector.emit(new Values(contract, stationNumber, availableStands));
        outputCollector.ack(input);
    }

    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields("city", "station_id", "available_stands"));
    }
}
```

Comment: You could set a breakpoint or just print the tuple directly and inspect it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default the "topic", "partition", "offset", "key", and "**value**" will be emitted to the "default" stream.

https://storm.apache.org/releases/2.4.0/storm-kafka-client.html

Use a RecordTranslator to change this.